# Rの行指定について

Tags: r

Rのプログラミングについて質問です。

データフレームから行を抽出するときに、
ランダムな数が入った変数で指定したいのですが、
下記のコードで行なったところ1行しか出力できません。

data[[a : a + b], "列名"]

a,b はともにfloor(runif)で取得した
整数が入っているのですが、
a行目しか出力されません。。

解決策をご存知の方教えていただけませんか？

Comment: `data[a:(a+b), "列名"]` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます！